# Существует ли гибрид C и C#?

Tags: c#, c

После C# переход на C слегонца фрустрирует. Дело не в сборке мусора, LINQ и метапрограммировании с компонентной моделью, которое я люблю использовать при программировании на C#. Понятно, что этого в C быть и не должно, не для тех целей язык. Дело в том, что в C# решены некоторые проблемы, которые можно было бы решить и в C, не меняя его идеологии. Может, существует такой компромиссный язык?

Что мне не нравится в C:

1. C разрешает обращаться к неинициализированным переменным.
2. В C не отследить арифметическое переполнение (правда, можно для этого сделать ассемблерную вставку, но она срабатывает только тогда, когда переполнение происходит в последней операции перед ассемблерной вставкой).
3. C разрешает писать функции, которые, хотя и должны возвращать значение, могут его не возвращать.
4. Не уверен, что это возможно в рамках архитектуры C, но хорошо бы иметь возможность всегда узнать длину массива, а не только когда он создан в стеке в пределах функции.
5. C разрешает проваливание в операторах `switch` после того, как по константе выполнились какие-нибудь инструкции.
6. Неудобный синтаксис для указателей на функцию. Я не представляю себе, как с помощью такого синтаксиса можно описать функцию, которая возвращает указатель на функцию, которая принимает или возвращает указатель на функцию.
7. При объявлении функций с переменным числом параметров не указывается тип этих параметров. Хотелось бы, чтобы опционально такая возможность была (в C# эта опциональность достигается наличием типа `object`). Да и сишный способ разбора этих параметров не отличается прозрачностью. Если бы функцию `scanf` можно было бы объявить как-нибудь так: `scanf(const char*, params void*[] p);`, то можно было бы проверить на этапе компиляции, что ей переданы именно адреса, а не непонятно что.
8. Синтаксис объявления переменных и формальных параметров функций в C неудачный, типы перемешаны с переменными (например, `int i, j[10], *p;`). Полагаю, неудобства в работе с указателями на функцию и переменным числом параметров растут оттуда.
9. В C имеет место некоторый бардачок с целочисленными типами данных. Мне нравится, что в C# каждый целочисленный тип называется строго одним ключевым словом, и нет чехарды с тем, что такое int: двух- или четырёхбайтное целое.
10. Ещё меня смущает адресная арифметика. Мне кажется, указатели надо было сделать неизменяемыми: мы получили некоторый адрес путём & или malloc, и дальше менять его всякими инкрементами не можем. Если хотим изменить значение указателя с помощью адресной арифметики, мы должны создать новый указатель.
11. Очень бесит, что нельзя объявить переменную цикла при объявлении цикла. Правда, в C++ вроде бы уже можно.
12. При работе с перечислениями значения указываются без префикса типа перечисления, с префиксом было бы нагляднее.
13. Непонятно, зачем при объявлении перечисления или структуры без `typedef` при использовании этих типов надо писать `struct ADDRESS` или `enum week_day` вместо просто `ADDRESS` или `week_day`.
14. При работе с битовыми полями хорошо бы было более чётко специфицировать порядок выделения бит. Например, с помощью дополнительной конструкции (типа того, что пишем после точки не только количество бит, но и номер, с которого начинаем).
15. При работе с перечислениями базовый числовой тип не указывается явно, только по используемым значениям перечисления.

Comment: > Очень бесит, что нельзя объявить переменную цикла при объявлении цикла.

Начиная с С11 вроде как можно.

А в чем причина перехода, если не секрет? С, как мне кажется, язык или для самообазования, или для совсем low-level компонент, которые потенциально могут использоваться на устройствах с 8мб оперативы и где о сишарпе речи просто не идет.

Comment: В связи со сменой работы.

Comment: @Modus, Вот, видимо, не только Вам это все не нравиться, и они делают С# и другие языки. Напишите свой Си с классами и переполнениями, и будет счастье.

Думаю, где-то так же рассуждали много лет назад Керриган и Риччи, смотря на ассемблер. Но тогда полученный С был пределом мечтаний. Хотя с тех пор си достаточно сильно поменялся.

По пунктам Ваших "замечаний". Многое на самом деле можно, многое именно так и должно работать. К примеру, структуры нужно просто правильно объявлять и не нужно будет писать постоянно struct.

Си, который от майкрософта, достаточно отсталый:)

Comment: Не нравится -- Си, не пишите на нем.

Посмотрите на Go, или D, или Ada, или ... ([языков много](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Hello_world)).

Может, они понравятся.

Comment: @KoVadim, правильно объявленные структуры - это про typedef?
До Кернигана и Ричи был Паскаль. Не думаю, что это было хуже ассемблера. Хотя чисто с точки зрения синтаксиса Си куда приятнее, скобочки куда лучше читаются.
У меня не майкрософтовский компилятор, а Borland C++ Builder 6.

Comment: @Modus, насколько я понимаю, тот Паскаль (появился в 1970 году) с его строгой типизацией и отсутствием кучи необходимых для реального программирования вещей совершенно не подходил для написания ОС.

Переменные цикла в его объявлении появились в C99 (-std=c99 для gcc).

Если не нравится писать `struct`, то можете сделать `typedef` (лично мне больше нравится, когда struct описывается явно).

Comment: @Modus: Вам, наверное, нужен [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/)?

Comment: Тогда уж D, скорее.

Answer (score 2):

А вот насчет описания указателей на функции, пожалуй Вы правы. С другой стороны, а в каком языке и как можно корректно описать функцию, которая принимает и возвращает себя?

--

В принципе, работающий вариант в Си можно описать, например, как-то так (только компилятор не сможет делать корректные проверки)

```
 typedef void * (*func)(void * (*)(), char *);
 ...
 void * foo (func f, char *msg) {
   ...
   return (f && f != foo) ? f(foo, msg) : foo;
 }
```

Пример, конечно же, практически бессмысленный (демонстрирует, что функция это по сути просто адрес (т.е. `void *`)).

Comment: Проверил. Такой typedef работает, и он решает проблему. С полученным псевдонимом можно работать как с делегатом C#.

Comment: @avp: C#, например, позволяет:

    delegate D D(D d);

Вот маленький [пример](http://ideone.com/DFjLys), а вообще это уходит в сторону Y-комбинатора ([[1]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx), [[2]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/779013/The-Y-Combinator-in-Csharp)) и прочей функциональщины.

Comment: @VladD, ага, здорово!

Наверное, в Си ключевое слово `function` (с возможностью forward declaration по аналогии со `struct`) решило бы проблему синтаксиса.

А может, просто я не могу написать набор правильных typedef...

Comment: @avp: я пробовал, тоже не выходит. Даже на C++ с его `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

1. В С переменная может быть натянута на какой-нибудь регистр. И тогда она уже не будет неинициализированной, хоть и записывать в нее никто в программе не будет
2. Все прекрасно отслеживается - настроить сопроцессор и он будет вызывать прерывания при переполнении.
3. Позабытый return ведет к неопределенному поведению.
4. Желаете странного. Массив, объявленный динамически - просто адрес в памяти. Возлагать на рантайм еще и обязанность помнить, сколько там этой памяти - больно жирное желание, особенно на микроконтроллерах, у которых этой памяти может быть всего 32 байта. Хотите знать размер - напишите свой код, обслуживающий хранение этого размера.
5. Оператор множественного выбора реализован как куча банальных переходов по меткам case. Естественно, что будет иметь место "проваливание", и зачастую оно очень удобно и позволяет писать более компактно. Просто не следует забывать о break.
6. Синтаксис для указателей на функции страшен только первые 116 раз. Потом наступает просветление.
7. Представьте себе, какую прорву кода надо втащить в рантайм для реализации такой хотелки. Хотите переменное число параметров - можете это реализовать при помощи массива указателей на них. Ничего сложного.
8. Синтаксис страшен, потому как очень подробен. Если выучить несколько правил, вроде того, что модификаторы * действуют строго на то, что справа и не лепить больше одной переменной на строку, уровень понимания становится выше.
9. Откройте для себя inttypes.h int32_t - вполне конкретное указание типа и размера.
10. Адресная арифметика - это то, что заставляет программы на C летать с ракетными скоростями и выжимать из камней ровно те гигафлопсы, которыми гордится intel в своих рекламах.
11. Как насчет C99? Хоть заобъявляйтесь.

И т.д. и т.п. Большинство ругани и хотелок от непонимания простого факта, что C предназначен конкретно для того, чтобы решительно выжать из железа по максимуму, но без фанатичной зубрежки ассемблера и регистров конкретного камня. Но при этом, знать камень все же нужно. C такой, каково наше вычислительное железо, и вы с этим ничего не сделаете. Хотите программировать ненапряжно - возвращайтесь к C# и прочему расслабону.

Comment: 4. Но тем не менее при выделении памяти через `malloc` рантайм помнит размер.

Comment: 6. У меня не наступило, ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: 10. Не уверен, что именно это главный плюс. Можете показать подтверждающий пример?

Comment: Есть реализации, которые размер в чистом виде не помнят из-за чего его определение - дорогая процедура.

Comment: (минус не мой) Но что им мешает вместо этого хранить размер массива?

Comment: @VladD то, что они массив хранят во внешней микросхеме, которую удобно читать / писать строго подряд, нежели носиться по ней случайным образом.

Аналогично и с 10 примером. У 286  машины в 16 битном режиме очень мало регистровых пар, способных хранить указатель, поэтому заведение каждый раз нового указателя превратит машкод в i like to move it, move it!

Comment: По поводу 10 всё равно не понимаю. Для случая массива адресная арифметика равносильна обыкновенному индексированию, и тем самым неинтересна. Для случая пробега по объекту она позволяет делать простую, но непереносимую между платформами сериализацию, и больше, кажется, ни для чего не годна.

Comment: Назад к 4, во внешней микросхеме при этом будет хранится, очевидно, не массив (потому что без длины), а последовательность байт/слов/чего угодно. А зачем из-за этого наказывать тех, кто выделяет массивы malloc'ом?

Comment: @VlaD речь идет о том, что стандарт C предоставляет программисту минимальную рабочую платформу, которая функционирует на огромном количестве железа. Всевозможные хотелки, вроде знания размера динамического массива и прочего, программист пусть делает себе сам.

Другой пример - во многих случаях, malloc может быть неудобен и неэффективен и его могут применять только для отхватывания большого блока, который уже собственными силами режется на блоки поменьше, а освобождается так вообще махом. Тогда возможность узнать размер блока становится лишней.

А 10 реализуется при помощи const

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31571/discussion-between-gbg-and-vladd).